# while exporting the dataset it downloads only one annotated image instead of 180 annotated image in cvat (online). provide solutions

Tags: image, annotations, cvat

The issue is with exporting data from CVAT Online, where only one annotated image is being downloaded instead of the expected 180. I've attempted exporting from both the task and job menus without success. I'm seeking solutions, particularly regarding collaboration settings or export configurations, to ensure the entire dataset can be successfully exported.
And i want to download mask images in format of segmentation mask 1.1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.